# Table name as variable parameter

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin

I made a function in pgadmin

```
create or replace function get_source2(a text)
returns integer as
$$
declare
    a text;
    geom geometry;
begin
    select get_source(geom) 
    from a;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

I want input a by table name How can I do? I try to like this

`select get_source2('postgis.center')`

but I get:

> ERROR: relation "a" does not exist LINE 2: from a help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
create or replace function get_source2(a text)
returns integer as
$$
declare
    geom geometry;
begin
  execute 'select get_source(geom) from '||quote_ident(a) into geom;
  return geom;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```